# how to make file when i press submit button in html file with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

**when i press the submit button value of id will get and i want to make file
but its showing an error for making file**

**code of html file:-**

```
<label for="">Make New File : </label>
    <input type="text" id="inputfilename">
    <p id="output"></p>
    <br>
    <button id="submitbutton" onclick="submit()">Make File</button>
```

**code for javascript and node js:-**

```
function submit()
{
    const filename = document.getElementById("inputfilename").value;
    console.log(filename);

    //make file
    // const filepath = `C:\Users\asus\Desktop${filesystem}`;
    // console.log(filepath);
    
    const filesystem = require('fs');
    filesystem.writeFileSync('xyz.txt','Hiii',(err)=>{
    if(err)
    {
        //   console.log('Error making file...');
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Error making file...";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // console.log("File is created...");
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "File is created!";
    }
    });
}
```

**but its showing error like this in console:-**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at submit (indexjs.js:10:24)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):15:50)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use javascript from client side you can use Blob and file-saver module for making a file.

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

var blob = new Blob(["Welcome to Websparrow.org."],
                { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });

saveAs(blob, "static.txt");
```

Answer (score -1):

*Js*

```
const filesystem = require('fs');
filesystem.writeFile(`demo.txt`, 'Hiii , Demo file content', (err) => {
    if (err) {
          console.log('Error making file...');
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log("File is created..."); 
    }
});
```

Comment: That won't work. The OP is trying to run code in the browser, not in Node.js.